# Mautic with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mautic

I've installed Mautic into an instance in Google Cloud and I am developing an app in NodeJS with Express. I need to connect Mautic with NodeJS, I want to create segments and add new leads into these segments. I googled it and I just found documentation in PHP.

Can I connect my app in NodeJS with Mautic?

Does have Mautic some documentation in NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

Mautic uses standard REST API which is agnostic to a programming language. You can authenticate via Oauth1, Oauth2a or BasicAuth.

API docs: https://developer.mautic.org/#rest-api

I also googled "[Mautic NodeJS](https://www.google.com/search?q=mautic%20nodejs)" and found this library that could be helpful: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mautic-api-node